# How to build the input pipeline for a Siamese Network in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Currently, I am trying to implement the experiment in the paper: *Siamese Neural Networks for One-shot Image Recognition* using Tensorflow.

The image set is Omniglot, in which each image can be loaded as an [105,105,1] array.

Since the input of Siamese network is a pair of images with same-or-different class, I need to preprocess the dataset as follows.

I transfer the Omniglot dataset into a [n,20,105,105,1] numpy array, where n represents the number of classes, in which each class has 20 examples of images of size [105,105,1].

Then I implement a function to return one pair of images:

```
def get_example(dataset):
"""
get one pair of images 
:param dataset: the set, eg. training set
:return: when label is 1, return a concatenated array of two imgs from same character
         when label is 0, return a concatenated array of two imgs from different characters
"""
# randint(0, x) generates 1 random numbers from 0 ~ x
set_upper = len(dataset)
set_lower = 0

# sample(range(0, 20), 2) generates 2 random numbers from 0 ~ 19
char_upper = 20
char_lower = 0

label = randint(0, 1)

if label:
    # randomly select one character from the set
    char = randint(set_lower, set_upper-1)
    rand_char = dataset[char]

    # randomly select two different images from the character
    a = b = 0
    while a == b:
        a, b = sample(range(char_lower, char_upper), 2)
    img_a = rand_char[a]
    img_b = rand_char[b]

else:
    # randomly select two characters from the set
    c1, c2 = sample(range(set_lower, set_upper), 2)
    rand_char1 = dataset[c1]
    rand_char2 = dataset[c2]

    # randomly select two images from two characters
    a, b = sample(range(char_lower, char_upper), 2)
    img_a = rand_char1[a]
    img_b = rand_char2[b]

img_input = np.concatenate((img_a, img_b), axis=0)
img_input = img_input[..., newaxis]
return img_input, label
```

So here is my question, how to group the images into batches, and how to feed them into the model in Tensorflow?

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to create a dataset as described in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays and use standard `tf.data.Dataset` operations like `shuffle` and `batch` to achieve your goal.